# Spy apps for iPhone 4 / jailbreaking without notice

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

My friend is in a rocky marriage, and has had a lot of money removed from her bank account using a forged signature.

Her husband has changed his behaviour lately, including spending much more time with his personal grooming etc.  She's really worried he may be cheating on her, and responsible for the missing money.

I've done a google search and found [this spy app](http://www.flexispy.com/spyphone-flexispy-apple-iphone.htm).  It says the phone needs to be jailbroken.

If her husband's phone is not jailbroken yet, will jailbreaking it be evident to him?  Do you have any other recommendations for spy apps on iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Jailbreaking will install Cydia on the iPhone, which isn't very easy to remove. A jailbreak may also cause general instability of the device, unusual behavior of apps, increased memory load, security problems (especially if the root password is left unchanged) and other problems. The device will change - even just subtle, but enough for someone used to the standard behavior to notice.

On a side note, I don't think that installing spyware on other people's devices is good idea. It may even be illegal, depending on your jurisdiction. A marriage counselor may be a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

When you jailbreak, Cydia will be installed. Since you want it to be unnoticed, follow these steps:

1. Jailbreak using your favourite [jailbreak](http://greenpois0n.com/) [tool](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/)
2. The jailbreak tool may install Cydia, or a loader to install Cydia. make sure you install it first.
3. Install the app through Cydia
4. Install SBSettings (and it's related packages)
5. Go to the settings of SBSettings (swipe the status bar) and select `Hide Icons`. Find Cydia and the jailbreak-related apps and hide them. It will respring the iPhone when you are done.

There will be an option under Settings (the iOS one) for Activator, which helps with the launching of SBSettings. I strongly recommend that you leave it there, but it is noticeable.

Lastly, it may be illegal, depending where you are, to install such software.